# Configure serverless framework not to upload to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Need to deploy a serverless function in aws lambda using serverless. Serverless uses aws Cloud formation to build the stack completely and uploads the module into S3. It uploads by default into S3, but the intended file is less than 10 mb which could be attached in aws lambda directly. How to configure the serverless.yml to achieve the scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

You've asked serverless to create a CloudFormation template that creates some lambdas. When AWS executes the template, it executes it in the cloud away from your computers local files. Thats why your code is packaged, uploaded to S3, and made available for CloudFormation use.

CloudFormation does allow for code to be inline in the template but serverless does not support this. And there is no way to ask CloudFormation to create a lambda without code attached for manual upload at a later date.

Frankly the cost to have the additional bucket and a few small files is minimal (if any). If the concern is the additional deployment bucket, you can [specify a deployment bucket](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/deploying/#tips) name for multiple serverless deployments.